# Heroku build failed can't find webpack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, webpack, webpacker

My Rails 6 heroku build can't seem to find a copy of webpack. I accidentally added `/tmp` to `.slugignore` which I believe is the cause of this issue, but I don't understand why. I have since remove `/tmp` from `.slugignore` but the problem still persists. The app has been building fine for years. It's like I was always relying on an old webpack? But `/tmp` should be empty when the heroku build starts? Very confused on this one. I've never used any node or webpack heroku buildpacks, but maybe I should?

Here is a snapshot of the error:

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
   Running: rake assets:precompile
   /tmp/build_6ab5739c16c73857f5e476d061484644/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.3/lib/active_record/type.rb:27: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
   /tmp/build_6ab5739c16c73857f5e476d061484644/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.3/lib/active_record/type/adapter_specific_registry.rb:9: warning: The called method `add_modifier' is defined here
   /tmp/build_6ab5739c16c73857f5e476d061484644/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:37: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
   /tmp/build_6ab5739c16c73857f5e476d061484644/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:111: warning: The called method `initialize' is defined here
   /tmp/build_6ab5739c16c73857f5e476d061484644/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:37: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
   /tmp/build_6ab5739c16c73857f5e476d061484644/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/ssl.rb:59: warning: The called method `initialize' is defined here
   yarn install v1.16.0
   [1/5] Validating package.json...
   error @1.7.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=14.0.0". Got "10.15.3"
   error Found incompatible module.
   info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
   autoprefixer: /tmp/build_6ab5739c16c73857f5e476d061484644/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss:5944:5: Gradient has outdated direction syntax. New syntax is like `to left` instead of `right`.
   autoprefixer: /tmp/build_6ab5739c16c73857f5e476d061484644/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss:9297:5: Gradient has outdated direction syntax. New syntax is like `to left` instead of `right`.
   Compiling...
   Compilation failed:
   sh: 1: /tmp/build_6ab5739c16c73857f5e476d061484644/node_modules/.bin/webpack: not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the heroku/nodejs heroku buildpack.